# How to click on text in a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

First time here. So I am making a twitter clone. The usernames and tweets are randomly generated and are populated in a dynamically created `<div>`.

I was wondering how to click on the username text in that dynamically created div with jQuery (the text in the div is just basic text) to initiate an action, such as `$('username').on.click()`.

I can do this with a div I create in html but can't do it with a dynamically created div in jQuery.

What I ultimately want to do is have only the tweets of the username appear, instead of the assorted tweets of all users.

I've been trying various things but haven't had any luck. Thanks for your help!

This is the jquery bit from the HTML file. It creates a div with info from the js file:

```
var index = streams.home.length - 1;
        while(index >= 0){
          var tweet = streams.home[index];
          var $tweet = $('<div id="tweetBody"</div>');
          //I'm trying to click on 'tweet.user' below
          $tweet.text(' ' + '@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + '\n' + tweet.created_at);
          $tweet.prependTo($body);
          $('#tweetBody').prepend(userPokemon);
              lastTweetIndex++;
          index -= 1;
        }
```

Here is the javascript from the js file:

```
window.streams = {};
streams.home = [];
streams.users = {};
streams.users.shawndrost = [];
streams.users.sharksforcheap = [];
streams.users.mracus = [];
streams.users.douglascalhoun = [];
window.users = Object.keys(streams.users);

// utility function for adding tweets to our data structures
var addTweet = function(newTweet){
  var username = newTweet.user;
  streams.users[username].push(newTweet);
  streams.home.push(newTweet);
};

// utility function
var randomElement = function(array){
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[randomIndex];
};

// random tweet generator
var opening = ['just', '', '', '', '', 'ask me how i', 'completely', 'nearly', 'productively', 'efficiently', 'last night i', 'the president', 'that wizard', 'a ninja', 'a seedy old man'];
var verbs = ['downloaded', 'interfaced', 'deployed', 'developed', 'built', 'invented', 'experienced', 'navigated', 'aided', 'enjoyed', 'engineered', 'installed', 'debugged', 'delegated', 'automated', 'formulated', 'systematized', 'overhauled', 'computed'];
var objects = ['my', 'your', 'the', 'a', 'my', 'an entire', 'this', 'that', 'the', 'the big', 'a new form of'];
var nouns = ['cat', 'koolaid', 'system', 'city', 'worm', 'cloud', 'potato', 'money', 'way of life', 'belief system', 'security system', 'bad decision', 'future', 'life', 'pony', 'mind'];
var tags = ['#techlife', '#burningman', '#sf', 'but only i know how', 'for real', '#sxsw', '#ballin', '#omg', '#yolo', '#magic', '', '', '', ''];

var randomMessage = function(){
  return [randomElement(opening), randomElement(verbs), randomElement(objects), randomElement(nouns), randomElement(tags)].join(' ');
};

// generate random tweets on a random schedule
var generateRandomTweet = function(){
  var tweet = {};
  tweet.user = randomElement(users);
  tweet.message = randomMessage();
  tweet.created_at = new Date();
  addTweet(tweet);
};

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  generateRandomTweet();
}

var scheduleNextTweet = function(){
  generateRandomTweet();
  setTimeout(scheduleNextTweet, Math.random() * 1500);
};
scheduleNextTweet();

// utility function for "write a tweet" functionality
// (note: not used by the rest of this file.)
var visitor = 'visitor';

var writeTweet = function(message){
  if(!visitor){
    throw new Error('set the global visitor property!');
  }
  var tweet = {};
  tweet.user = visitor;
  tweet.message = message;
  return tweet;
  //addTweet(tweet);
};
```

If applicable, here is some of the CSS:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(136,191,232) 40%,rgb(112,176,224) 70%, rgb(157,213,58) 50%,rgb(161,213,79) 80%);
  background-image: url(http://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/8bit_wallpaper13.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#tweetBody{
  top: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 102, 1.0);
  text-align: right;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 550px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgb(14,110,65);
 }

 #tweetBody:hover {
   background-color: rgba(82, 146, 219, 0.7);
   margin-left: 490px;
   margin-right: 290px;
   transition: 0.3s;
   color: black;
}
```

[Here is what it looks like. You can see the username I want to click on next to the pokemon. This feed updates with new tweets automatically and so they must be dynamically created divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFKWf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow works best when you share a small example of what you are having troubles with.

Comment: you could take a look at here, to create a [mcve]

Comment: *"how to click on the username text with jQuery"* - Are you asking how to make jQuery simulate a click, or asking how to write code that *responds* to a click from the user? Either way, please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML.

Comment: Hi! Thanks Ryan and Mark, I will do that. To your question, nnnnnn, I'm looking to have code that responds to a click from the user. I know how to do this for divs created in html, but I'm trying to have code that responds when a user clicks on some text in a dynamically created div. I'll try and post an example!  Thanks for your help, all! - K

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="username"><span>ronaldo</span></div>
then
$('#username span').click(function(){
// code of you at here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('username')` is attempting to match against an *element* named username.

e.g.

```
<username>test</username>
```

You can use `$('.username')` to match css classes, and `$('#username')` to match CSS ID's.

class:`<div class="username">` or id:`<div id="username">`

in order to create a click handler for jQuery https://api.jquery.com/click/

You can do `$('.username').click(function(event){ //code });`

I suggest you read up on css selectors, as well as review the JQuery Docs some more. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/